# click event does not fire when coupled with css :active

Tags: jquery, css, events, jquery-ui

I have created a navigation menu where, when clicking on a link, a jquery dialog box opens.

On these same links in my css I have:
`.navigationLinkButton:active { background:rgb(200,200,200); }`
The dialog box is attached simply with:
`$("#link").click(function() {$(this).dialog("open")});`

Occasionally (about every 4-5 clicks) when a user clicks the link the dialog box does not open, and only the background color of the link changes. Clicking the link again will open the dialog box. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The background colour seems to be irrelevant and confusing matters in this question. What you have is a javascript issue.

Comment: When I remove the :active css property completely, the issue goes away. The issue also goes away when I change the color via JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you haven't used the `#link` ID more than once on the page.

If your links are `<a>` elements (I assume they must be since you're using :active) try `return false;` at the end of your `click()` handler.

This will disable the default behavior of the link which may be refreshing the page.

```
$("#link").click( function() {
    $(this).dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#link").click(function() {$(this).dialog("open")}
```

should be

```
$("#link").click(function(){$(this).dialog("open")});
```

Also make sure that you only have one #link on the page. If you don't, try using a class instead (".link")

Comment: The `)` issue is most likely a typo. Otherwise, OP's code would never work.

Comment: yes, it was a typo. I do actually have a ')'. I do also have one #link on the page.